# How to convert hyphen-delimited tag names to camel case

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like -

```
<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>
```

I want to remove hyphens (`-`) and uppercase the single alpha character following each removed hyphen.  I.e. convert from hyphen-delimited words to "CamelCase".

Like -

```
<phoneResidence></phoneResidence><maritalStatus>1</maritalStatus><phoneOnRequest></phoneOnRequest>
```

How to do this?

Comment: My input is "`<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>`" and output will be "`<phoneResidence></phoneResidence><maritalStatus>1</maritalStatus><phoneOnRequest></phoneOnRequest>`"

Comment: I have adapted my code it will now only take into account the tagNames for the replacement operations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple, actually. Just read each character of the input string and use a `boolean` to decide if the character should be added as-is, capitalized, or ignored ():

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>";
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        boolean capitalizeNext = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char thisChar = input.charAt(i);
            if (thisChar == '-') {
                capitalizeNext = true;
            } else if (capitalizeNext) {
                output.append(String.valueOf(thisChar).toUpperCase());
                capitalizeNext = false;
            } else {
                output.append(thisChar);
                capitalizeNext = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
<phoneResidence></phoneResidence><maritalStatus>1</maritalStatus><phoneOnRequest></phoneOnRequest>
```

---

**Same Code w/ Additional Comments:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>";

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        // This is used to determine if the next character should be capitalized
        boolean capitalizeNext = false;

        // Loop through each character of the input String
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

            // Obtain the current character from the String
            char thisChar = input.charAt(i);

            if (thisChar == '-') {

                // If this character is a hyphen, set the capitalizeNext flag, but do NOT add this character to 
                // the output string (ignore it)
                capitalizeNext = true;

            } else if (capitalizeNext) {

                // The last character was a hyphen, so capitalize this character and add it to the output string
                output.append(String.valueOf(thisChar).toUpperCase());

                // Reset the boolean so we make a new determination on the next pass
                capitalizeNext = false;

            } else {

                // Just a regular character; add it to the output string as-is
                output.append(thisChar);

                // Reset the boolean so we make a new determination on the next pass
                capitalizeNext = false;

            }
        }

        // Just print the final output
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: yes true, your answer is so complete and you deserve an upvote from me! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 8 functional interfaces there has been a `String#replaceAll()` that takes a transformation function to modify the matched subsequences "on the fly" and build the final output.

First, A Warning: Regexes are fantastic, incredibly powerful tools ***for a certain class of problem***.  Before applying regex you must determine if the problem is amenable.  Ordinarily processing XML is the antithesis of a regex-amenable problem, except in this case where the goal is to treat the input as merely a string and not as XML.  (However read carefully the Caveat below)

Here is a famous quote from Jamie Zawinski in 1997:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

## Solution

With those caveats, here's the code for your question:

```
    String input="<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-[a-zA-Z]").matcher(input);
    // Do all the replacements in one statement using the functional replaceAll()
    String result = m.replaceAll(s -> s.group().substring(1).toUpperCase());
```

## Explanation

The regex matches a single hyphen followed by any single alphabetic character, upper or lowercase.  The `replaceAll()` scans the input using the `Matcher`.  At every match it invokes the lambda (functional shorthand for an anonymous class with a single `apply()` method) passing in a `String` argument containing the matched text.  Whatever the lambda returns is then substituted into output string being built by the `replaceAll()` method, in place of the matched string.

## Caveat

The solution given above is completely blind to the structure of the XML it will change any `-a` combination (where `a` stands for any letter) and replace it with just `A` (where `A` stands for an upper-case letter), regardless where it appears.

In the example you gave, this pattern occurred only in the tag names.  If however, there are other parts of the file that contain (or can contain) that pattern then those instances will also be replaced.  This could be a problem if that pattern occurs in text data (i.e. stuff ***not** inside, but **between** the tags*) or as an attribute value.  This approach of applying a regex to the entire file blindly is kind of the chainsaw approach.  If you really, really need a chainsaw you use it.

However, if it turns out a chainsaw is too powerful and your actual task requires more finesse, then you would need to switch to a real XML parser (the JDK includes a good one), which can handle all the subtleties.  It delivers to you the various syntactic bits and pieces such as tag name, attribute names, attribute values, text, etc. separately, so that you can explicitly decide which parts are to be affected.  You'd still use the `replaceAll()` above but apply it only to the parts where it was needed.

Almost as a rule, you will ABSOLUTELY NOT use regexes to process XML, or parse strings containing nested or escaped quotes, or parse CSV or TSV files.  Those data formats are not normally suitable domains for using regexes.

Comment: Well, that is incredibly simple! Kudos on the 2-line implementation.

Comment: I don't understand it all (regex is not my friend), but it works :)

Comment: @Zephyr I added an explanation

Comment: @JimGarrison: Thanks for this great answer, +1! I have provided a prototype of a code that will take only into account the tagnames for the replacement and will not affect the values of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the values of the elements your XML file do not have any hyphens in them, or if it does not matter if they are affected by the change then you can use the following code:

**Code:**

```
String input="<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>";
//this regex will match all letters preceded by a hyphen
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-[a-zA-Z]").matcher(input);
//use a string builder to manipulate the intermediate strings that are constructed
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int last = 0;

//for each match
while (m.find()) {
    //append the substring between the last match (or the beginning of the string to the beginning of the current match 
    sb.append(input.substring(last, m.start()));
    //change the case to uppercase of the match
    sb.append(m.group(0).toUpperCase());
    //set last to the end of the current match
    last = m.end();
}
//add the rest of the input string          
sb.append(input.substring(last));
//remove all the hyphens and print the string
System.out.println(sb.toString().replaceAll("-", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
<phoneResidence></phoneResidence><maritalStatus>1</maritalStatus><phoneOnRequest></phoneOnRequest>
```

**Improvement:**

If you have hyphens in the values of the elements of your XML and you do **NOT** want them to be affected by this change then you can use the following code (this simplified version does work only if you do not have attributes in your elements (you can add the logic for attributes) and works for small XML trees (you might have to increase the stack size for bigger XML documents to avoid `stack overflow` errors):

**Code:**

```
String input="<contact-root><phone-residence>abc-abc</phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request><empty-node></empty-node></phone-on-request><empty-node/><not-really-empty-node>phone-on-request</not-really-empty-node></contact-root>";      
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(input)));          
StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
xmlTrasversal(doc.getDocumentElement(),-1, strBuild);
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(strBuild.toString());
```

**Functions used:**

```
  public static String capitalizeNext(String input){

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-[a-zA-Z]").matcher(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int last = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            sb.append(input.substring(last, m.start()));
            sb.append(m.group(0).toUpperCase());
            last = m.end();
        }           
        sb.append(input.substring(last));
        return (sb.toString().replaceAll("-", ""));

  }

  public static void xmlTrasversal(Element e, int depth, StringBuilder strBuild)
  {
        ++depth;
        String spaces="  ";
        spaces=String.join("", Collections.nCopies(depth, spaces));
        if(!e.hasChildNodes())
            strBuild.append(spaces+"<"+capitalizeNext(e.getNodeName())+"/>"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        else if(e.getChildNodes().getLength()==1 && !(e.getChildNodes().item(0) instanceof Element))
        {
            strBuild.append(spaces+"<"+capitalizeNext(e.getNodeName())+">");
            strBuild.append(e.getTextContent());
        }
        else
        {
            strBuild.append(spaces+"<"+capitalizeNext(e.getNodeName())+">"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }

        for (int i=0; i<e.getChildNodes().getLength();i++) 
        {
             if (e.getChildNodes().item(i) instanceof Element) {
                 xmlTrasversal((Element) e.getChildNodes().item(i), depth, strBuild);
            }
        }
        if(e.getChildNodes().getLength()==1 && !(e.getChildNodes().item(0) instanceof Element))
            strBuild.append("</"+capitalizeNext(e.getNodeName())+">"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        else if(e.hasChildNodes() && (e.getChildNodes().item(0) instanceof Element))
            strBuild.append(spaces+"</"+capitalizeNext(e.getNodeName())+">"+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

  }
```

**Output for input string:**

```
<contactRoot>
  <phoneResidence>abc-abc</phoneResidence>
  <maritalStatus>1</maritalStatus>
  <phoneOnRequest>
    <emptyNode/>
  </phoneOnRequest>
  <emptyNode/>
  <notReallyEmptyNode>phone-on-request</notReallyEmptyNode>
</contactRoot>
```

Comment: whats the use of the `regex` variable ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud: Thanks a lot! Nice pick, I have removed it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    String str = "<phone-residence></phone-residence><marital-status>1</marital-status><phone-on-request></phone-on-request>";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(str,"-");
    while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
        sb.append(WordUtils.capitalize(stk.nextToken()));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```